# How to obtain addresses of structure members

Tags: c, linker, keil

I'm doing testing of a project based on Cortex-M0. The firmware is developed in C using Keil (v. 4.71.2) and ARM Linker (v. 5.03). I have read/write access to the RAM which I use to simulate failures, and I need to find out addresses of variables I need to modify.

Right now I'm using the linker map file which is very handy for scalar global variables:

```
myvar        0x00005978   Data      4  file1.o(.constdata)
```

Here I know that writing 4 bytes at address 0x00005978 will alter the variable `myvar`. However, I cannot apply the same approach for global structures:

```
mystruct     0x00020000   Data     400 file2.o(.data)
```

I have the start address of `mystruct`, however, I have troubles to access `mystruct.module2.config.myvar`. Since the code is still being developed, new fields are added to `mystruct.module1` and the address of `mystruct.module2` changes.

Is it possible to force the linker to output the addresses of individual fields in the structure?

As a workaround I declare a global variable with the address I want:

```
uint32_t * const myvar_ptr = &mystruct.module2.config.myvar;
```

Then I can find the address of `myvar_ptr` in the linker map and read it to obtain the address of `mystruct.module2.config.myvar`. However, this approach wastes 4 bytes of ROM to store each pointer, and ROM size is strictly limited, so I cannot declare 100 extra pointers targeting each field of `mystruct`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe you can add some test code that print: the base address of the structure and the addresses of the members. From that you can determine the offsets and use those with the base address you got from the linker map. This code can be outside the program itself; you only need to know the offsets so you do not need to include it in the prgram.

Comment: No, the linker does not know about struct members, only about symbols with external linkage, in your case the global variable itself. You may get the offset of the member using another technique and the add it to the global variable address.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie that's a bright idea, thanks! I will try to include the header files defining the structure in a VS project and print the relative offsets. Not sure if VS will use the same alignment as Keil though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted in a comment, structure alignment may be an issue. It looks like the Keil compiler does support the [pack()](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_cjafeedg.htm) `#pragma` so you can control the alignment of struct members. You can then use the .MAP file to get the starting address of the struct, and use the C include file that defines the struct to calculate the offsets of the individual members.

Comment: Unfortunately my project fails to build with `pack()` (plenty of `cannot assing __packed int32* to int32*` errors). Anyway, Visual Studio and Keil *seem* to align the structure in the same way (`sizeof(mystruct)` is the same). So I guess I'll have to do without `pack` and hope for the best.